# Get or inject Lagom application context LagomApplicationContext

Tags: applicationcontext, lagom

Exist any way to get `LagomApplicationContext`? I would like to use play configuration object `play.api.Configuration` form `playContext` - composition:

```
sealed trait LagomApplicationContext {
  /**
   * The Play application loader context.
   */
  val playContext: Context
}
```

Any ideas or suggestion how to do it? Is Exist some DI?

I need to use values from application.conf the same like in this example: 
https://www.webkj.com/play-framework/play-scala-2.5-reading-config-using-di

Comment: play.api.Configuration can be injected directly into your class constructors.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is true - but only it is possible to inject in controller level:

```
class OnlineDiscountTagImpl @Inject() (cache : CacheApi) extends Controller
```